# Почему выдаёт ошибку: "Групповая функция не является одногруппной"

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Формулировка запроса:

Вычислить предполагаемую прибыль от каждого из незавершенных проектов (Прибыль вычисляется как стоимость проекта минус затраты; затраты = зарплаты * время в месяцах).

```
Select name, 
       cost, 
       projects.cost - MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(projects.DATE_END_REAL), TO_DATE(projects.date_beg)) * SUM(employees.salary)  
from projects
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENTS_EMPLOYEES on (departments_employees.department_id = projects.department_id)
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES on (departments_employees.employee_id = EMPLOYEES.id)
Where projects.DATE_END_REAL > SYSDATE
```

Comment: Кривая логика. Использована групповая функция SUM(). Запрос не содержит GROUP BY - в этом случае весь набор записей является одной группой. В этом случае выходной набор не может содержать полей, не являющихся аргументом групповой функции.

Comment: Даже если отгруппировать по project name и cost, выдаёт, что это не является выражением GROUP BY.

Comment: Группировка должна быть по **всем** полям, не являющимся аргументом `SUM`, у вас там полно ещё полей. Возможно, вам по `EMPLOYEES` надо отдельный запрос делать и там `SUM`, а потом уже с `projects` делать `JOIN` выше по иерархии.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Crazy Elf!